# Resend Code using Firebase Authentication in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

As there is no direct method to resend code once the code has already been sent , I am trying to resend it once again with following method :

```
 func sendOTPGetVerfID(phoneNum: String, completion: @escaping((_ verificationID: String?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {

      PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber( phoneNum , uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in

        if let error = error {
            QL1(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
        // ...
        QL1("VerificationID : \(verificationID ?? "")")
        completion(verificationID,nil)
    }
}
```

Issue here is, I am not able to receive the verificationID second time, calling the above method
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Call requestOtp() method on resend OTP button click.

```
import FirebaseAuth

func requestOtp() {
let phNo = "Your phone number"
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phNo, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        // Sign in using the verificationid and the code sent to the user
        // ...
      UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
    }
}
```

Verify Code with Auth:

```
func verifyNumberWith(verificationCode: String) {
  let verificationID=UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"authVerificationID")
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
        withVerificationID: verificationID ?? "",
        verificationCode: verificationCode)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        //Do your actions. 
    }
}
```

Comment: same thing I did, but issue is I'm not getting verification ID second time.